# How do you tell whether a string is an IP or a hostname

Tags: java, ip-address, hostname

So you have a String that is retrieved from an admin web UI (so it is definitely a String). How can you find out whether this string is an IP address or a hostname in Java?

Update: I think I didn't make myself clear, I was more asking if there is anything in the Java SDK that I can use to distinguish between IPs and hostnames? Sorry for the confusion and thanks for everybody who took/will take the time to answer this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a regular expression with this pattern:

```
\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b
```

That will tell you if it's an IPv4 address.

Comment: I think just testing for the digit pattern is more than enough, if you need real range validation, regex is really not the best way to do it.

Comment: Doesn't work. When I copy and paste your RegEx into https://regex101.com, and search for a string of 192.168.1.1, it says no match.

Answer (score 2):

You can see if the string matches the number.number.number.number format, for example:

```
\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b
```

will match anything from `0 - 999`.

Anything else you can have it default to hostname.

Comment: 999.999.999.999 is not a valid ip format. your regex needs to be more specific

Comment: don't think its a valid host name either

Answer (score 2):

Do we get to make the assumption that it *is* one or the other, and not something completely different?  If so, I'd probably use a regex to see if it matched the "dotted quad" format.

Answer (score 1):

```
URI validator = new URI(yourString);
```

That code will validate the IP address or Hostname. (It throws a malformed URI Exception if the string is invalid)

If you are trying to distinguish the two..then I miss read your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a security manager with the `InetAddress.getByName(addr)` call.

If the addr is not a dotted quad, `getByName` will attempt to perform a connect to do the name lookup, which the security manager can capture as a `checkConnect(addr, -1)` call, resulting in a thrown SecurityException that you can catch.

You can use `System.setSecurityManager()` if you're running fully privileged to insert your custom security manager before the `getByName` call is made.

Answer (score 1):

It is not as simple as it may appear, there are some ambiguities around characters like hyphens, underscore, and square brackets '-', '_', '[]'.

The Java SDK is has some limitations in this area.  When using InetAddress.getByName it will go out onto the network to do a DNS name resolution and resolve the address, which is expensive and unnecessary if all you want is to detect host vs address.  Also, if an address is written in a slightly different but valid format (common in IPv6) doing a string comparison on the results of InetAddress.getByName will not work.

[The IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) will do it.  The javadoc is available at the link.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager.

```
static void check(HostName host) {
    try {
        host.validate();
        if(host.isAddress()) {
            System.out.println("address: " + host.asAddress());
        } else {
            System.out.println("host name: " + host);
        }
    } catch(HostNameException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HostName host = new HostName("1.2.3.4");
    check(host);
    host = new HostName("1.2.a.4");
    check(host);
    host = new HostName("::1");
    check(host);
    host = new HostName("[::1]");
    check(host);
    host = new HostName("1.2.?.4");
    check(host);  
}
```

Output:

```
address: 1.2.3.4
host name: 1.2.a.4
address: ::1
address: ::1
1.2.?.4 Host error: invalid character at index 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just to a regexp match on it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [InetAddress#getAllByName(String hostOrIp)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getAllByName-java.lang.String-) - if `hostOrIp` is an IP-address the result is an array with single InetAddress and it's `.getHostAddress()` returns the same string as `hostOrIp`.

```java
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class IPvsHostTest {
    private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOG = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(IPvsHostTest.class);

    @org.junit.Test
    public void checkHostValidity() {
        Arrays.asList("10.10.10.10", "google.com").forEach( hostname -> isHost(hostname));
    }
    private void isHost(String ip){
        try {
            InetAddress[] ips = InetAddress.getAllByName(ip);
            LOG.info("IP-addresses for {}", ip);
            Arrays.asList(ips).forEach( ia -> {
                LOG.info(ia.getHostAddress());
            });
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            LOG.error("Invalid hostname", e);
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
IP-addresses for 10.10.10.10
10.10.10.10
IP-addresses for google.com
64.233.164.100
64.233.164.138
64.233.164.139
64.233.164.113
64.233.164.102
64.233.164.101
```

Answer (score 0):

This code still performs the DNS lookup if a host name is specified, but at least it skips the reverse lookup that may be performed with other approaches:

```
   ...
   isDottedQuad("1.2.3.4");
   isDottedQuad("google.com");
   ...

boolean isDottedQuad(String hostOrIP) throws UnknownHostException {
   InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName(hostOrIP);
   boolean b = inet.toString().startsWith("/");
   System.out.println("Is " + hostOrIP + " dotted quad? " + b + " (" + inet.toString() + ")");
   return b;
}
```

It generates this output:

```
Is 1.2.3.4 dotted quad? true (/1.2.3.4)
Is google.com dotted quad? false (google.com/172.217.12.238)
```

Do you think we can expect the toString() behavior to change anytime soon?